# iOS-Ui not response when tabbar click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbar, tabbarcontroller

I used a custom tabbar and one of tabs loaded in a Separate Storyboard.
When I click on this special tab for first time, the data is fetched from the server and until the data is completely loaded, the app UI freezes.

It delays just the first time that the data is loaded from the server.

How can I make the app responsive and load everything in background?

init Method my Rootcontroller.m:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        TGNavigationController * wallpaperController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"story_main"];



 _mainTabsController = [[TGMainTabsController alloc] initWithPresentation:_presentation];
        [_mainTabsController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_contactsController, _callsController, wallpaperController, _accountSettingsController, nil]];
```

P.S.: Other tabs implement only by code and don't use the storyboard at all.

Comment: show the code where the server call is placed.

Comment: actually the problem is not in that part , because i added this tab from separate project  that load every thing behind splash screen.i think its  related  to how call this storyboard without user waiting for  loading data.

Comment: A Splash screen is shown before loading this separate story board?

Comment: in my separate project,  the answer is yes but in mytabbar i removed it.

Comment: Don't you think that server call is causing freeze?

Comment: server is work very well.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not doing your server call in the main thread?

Comment: Try to fetch your data from the server using the background thread.